# Issue displaying hamburger menu using material design lite

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design

I've been searching for an answer on how to display the hamburger icon using material design lite css framework. I read similar questions of mine and tried the answers but no luck for me. If anyone knows and used this framework before kindly help me.

HTML:



 
 
 Home

```
</head>
<body>
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">
   Foo
      </span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">BAR</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">BAR</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">BAR</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">BAR</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.min.js"></script>
<script>
componentHandler.upgradeDom(); //code taken from other answers but nothin happen
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Material design doesn't (typically) use a hamburger icon. More common would be the vertical ellipses. See the [Menus section](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section) of the documentation. If you want to use a drawer layout, there's documentation in the [Layouts section](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout).

Comment: @StephenThomas, that's what i mean. The icon when using a drawer layout. It doesn't appear.

Comment: not enough info in your snippet to say. are you including the stylesheet (including the icons)? is the javascript running? why not use the latest version? etc. check out the mdl documentation for proper use

Comment: Yes, all stylesheets snd scripts are included.  I used the cdn one. Anyways thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening in mobile mode. it will appear. 
If you really want hamburger icon in browser mode try using other layouts like Fixed header from MDL.

and also please check if you have included.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?           family=Material+Icons">
```

which load the icons